# Scraping multiple websites with the same theme

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

```
const PORT = 5000;
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import cheerio from "cheerio";

const app = express();

const tomsHardware = "https://www.tomshardware.com/best-picks/best-gaming-mouse";
const pcGamer = "https://www.pcgamer.com/the-best-gaming-mouse/";

const requestOne = axios.get(tomsHardware);
const requestTwo = axios.get(pcGamer);

const mice = []

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Welcome to my climate change API!');
});

app.get('/mouse', (req, res) => {
    axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo])
        .then((response) => {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);

            $('.product__title').each(function (index, elem) {
                const title = $(this).text();
                mice.push({
                    title
                });
            });
            res.json(mice)
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

I am trying to scrape both of theses of these websites and I am getting "object is not iterable"
also I am not very sure about scraping both of them as they are using the same theme as it appears and they use the same class name.

Comment: I get a different error than you, `Error: cheerio.load() expects a string`, but `response` is an array of two responses, so you probably want to use `response[0].data` or iterate over both responses and dump each one into cheerio separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` is actually an array of two responses, so you'll need to loop over that array and parse each response's HTML separately:

```js
app.get('/mouse', (req, res) => {
  axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo])
    .then(responses => {
      for (const response of responses) {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  
        $('.product__title').each(function () {
          mice.push({title: $(this)text()});
        });
      }

      res.json(mice);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Note that `const mice = []` is declared outside the handler, so on each request, this array will continually grow with repeated elements. You might want to move it into the request handler closure to rebuild it on every request.